# grep, howto combine regular and invert match when invert pattern is part of regular pattern

Tags: linux, grep

I'm facing the task of extracting all records that either contains the string "no issue" or does not contain the string "issue" and wonder if this can be achieved with a single call to grep. I know that this can be done using two calls, e.g.

```
grep "no issue" FILE > NEWFILE
grep -v "issue" FILE >> NEWFILE
```

However that will mess up the original order of the records so not an option as the order is of importance.

Comment: No, that does not take into account that invert match is sub string in string to match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `gnu grep`:

```sh
grep -Pv '(?<!\bno )issue\b' file
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<!\bno )`: Negative lookbehind that asserts a failure if we have word `no` followed by a space before current position
- `issue\b`: Match word `issue`

Or using `gnu awk`:

```sh
awk '/\<no issue\>/ || !/\<issue\>/' file
```

Comment: Cool regex, however isn't it boils down to grep -v "issue\b" ?

Comment: No `grep -v "issue\b"` will skip matching `no issue` also

Comment: I see, makes sense, but the initial question had "no issues" and "issue" as far as I remember.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, was a typo that I've edited once I saw it. Dropping "\b" in the regex seems to also account for the mixed case originally posted.